# Creating a Singleton with Multiple Service Registrations Using DryIoc

Tags: c#, dryioc

## The Problem

I'm trying to register a singleton using DryIoc, but container is returning multiple instances of my singleton class. The singleton class is registered as the implementation type for multiple different service interfaces. When any of the aforementioned service interfaces is requested from DryIoc, I expect to get the same instance of my singleton class back, but that's not happening and I don't know why.

## An Example

Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do. In this example, I have a class, `Foo` that I would like to use as the singleton implementation for interfaces `IFoo` and `IBar`. In other words, when either `IFoo` or `IBar` are resolved from the container, I'd like for the same instance of `Foo` to be returned.

#### The Service Interfaces

```cs
interface IFoo
{   
}
interface IBar
{   
}
```

#### The Singleton (Implementation) Class

```cs
class Foo : IFoo, IBar
{
}
```

#### The Test

```cs
Container container = new Container();
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.Register<IBar, Foo>(Reuse.Singleton);

object foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
object bar = container.Resolve<IBar>();
Assert.AreSame(foo, bar); // Why does this fail?
```

## Considered Solutions

I've considered using DryIoc's `RegisterInstance` method but that would require the class to be manually created and I'm trying to avoid that because, unlike the simplified example above, the real-world class has dependencies of its own.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Register` method adds separate / independent registrations to the container. You need to specifically say to use the same registration for multiple services.

#### Option 1: [RegisterMany](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RegisterResolve#markdown-header-registermany)

```
// registers with Foo interfaces and itself. Remove @nonPublicServiceTypes to restrict for public types
container.RegisterMany<Foo>(Reuse.Singleton, nonPublicServiceTypes: true);

Assert.AreSame(container.Resolve<IFoo>(), container.Resolve<IBar>());
```

#### Option 2: [RegisterMapping](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RegisterResolve#markdown-header-registermapping)

```
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.RegisterMapping<IBar, IFoo>(); // maps to the IBar registration

Assert.AreSame(container.Resolve<IFoo>(), container.Resolve<IBar>());
```

#### Other:

Manually delegate the resolution as in @Fyodor answer.

Comment: For me RegisterMany and RegisterMapping do not work with ResolveMany<IFoo>, where IFoo already has services before registering Foo. The other solution by Fyodor does work but doesn't look very pretty...

Answer (score 4):

DryIoc's concept of "reuse" applies to services, not implementations. Your registrations are for two different services (`IFoo` and `IBar`), so they get different reuses, and the fact that they share implementation (`Foo`) does not apply here.

To achieve your goal, you can register the services via `made` that redirects to the implementation:

```
container.Register<Foo>( Reuse.Singleton );
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>( made: Made.Of( () => ReturnThis( Arg.Of<Foo>() ) ), reuse: Reuse.Singleton );
container.Register<IBar, Foo>( made: Made.Of( () => ReturnThis( Arg.Of<Foo>() ) ), reuse: Reuse.Singleton );

// Where ReturnThis is define thusly:
static T ReturnThis<T>( T t ) => t;
```

(you need the `ReturnThis` call, because naked `Made.Of( () => Arg.Of<Foo>() )` doesn't work; `Made` always expects a method call)